# Cannot access packaged custom field via rest api

Tags: managed-package, custom-field

I have made a managed package which contains few custom field. Till now it was not having any issues, but today someone installed that package in a group edition salesforce account, and he is not able to access the package custom field for eg `Account.MindMatrix__isPartner__c`.

The rest api is giving error that account does not have any such field.

Comment: Does the user have FLS to that field?

Comment: how do I check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Group Edition, Field Level Security is controlled by the page layout. Try adding field missing field(s) to the page layout, and you should then be able to query them. By default, installing a package doesn't modify the default page layouts, so they need to be modified manually to finish granting access.